# how to import LDAP user passwords into keycloak

Tags: ldap, single-sign-on, keycloak

I'm having a problem with an integration of IDAP users to keycloak, it imports all users and their information, it just can't log in with users already registered in IDAP using the same password and user and in keycloak the information appears normally but the credentials are empty, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

LDAP's user password did not save into Keycloak. Keycloak ask to LDAP server when user Login even if all other information import into Keycloak.

This is [source code](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/federation/ldap/src/main/java/org/keycloak/storage/ldap/idm/store/ldap/LDAPIdentityStore.java#L348) for checking password in LDAP.

And here official documentation said in [Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP) and Active Directory](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_user-storage-federation)

```
An exception exists for synchronizing passwords. Keycloak never imports passwords. Password validation always occurs on the LDAP server.
```